# How can I use Promises and Cursors together while remaining pure?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, immutability, indexeddb

In my classes, I've been learning indexeddb and how to handle asynchronous-ity. In the interest of stretching myself and learning more, I've been trying to use the functional paradigm in my code.

I'd been using cursors before but I've realized that my code isn't completely immutable or stateless, which bothers me. I was wondering if there was a way to use cursors without having to resort to pushing elements to an array.

Currently, I'm using something like:

```
async function getTable(){
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      const db = await connect();
      const transaction = await db.transaction(["objectStore"], "readonly");
      const store = await transaction.objectStore("objectStore");
      var myArray = [];
      store.openCursor().onsuccess = function(evt) {                   
         var cursor = evt.target.result;
         if (cursor) {
            myArray.push(cursor.value);
            //I don't want to use push, because it's impure. See link:
            cursor.continue();
         } else {
            resolve(myArray);
      }
   }
}

//link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional_programming
```

And it works fine. But it's not pure, and it uses push. I'd like to learn another way to do it, if there is one.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you further describe what you mean by "mutable"?

Comment: @guest271314 probably from redux background in which he means that outer variables are being modified. Ucenna, db calls are mutable AFAIK and the word that you are looking for is pure function not mutable

Comment: @guest271314 Mutable as in changing or liable to change. I'm referring to how myArray list goes through a cycle of being [entry1], [entry1, entry2], and so on. I'd like it to not do this. I'd rather not use myArray.push() and would prefer to use .map(), .reduce(), or something.

Comment: @user1533609 Thank you! I'll change my post to clarify.

Comment: How are `.map()` and `.reduce()` related to an array being "mutable" or "immutability"? Have you tried using `Object.freeze()`?

Comment: @guest271314 They're immutable because they return a new array rather than changing the old one. They're not super applicable here because of the nature of cursor. I hadn't heard of Object.freeze() I'll look into it. Thanks! edit: Object.freeze() isn't what I'm looking for. I want my code to not be changing my objects in the first place. Object.freeze would be a good thing to make sure, I'm not coding wrong in the first place. But at this point I know I'm coding wrong, so Object.freeze would just confirm that.

Comment: _"And it works fine. But it's not pure, and it uses push. I'd like to learn another way to do it, if there is one."_ , _"But at this point I know I'm coding wrong, so Object.freeze would just confirm that."_ What is the issue with code at Question? What is requirement?

Comment: What do you mean by "pure" as relating to composing code?

Comment: @guest271314 It's not pure, myArray mutates. It works fine as in it functions. But it's wrong because it lacks purity and doesn't really fit in with the functional paradigm.

Comment: @guest271314 It's not pure, because it has a state. There's one point in the code where myArray == [entry1] and another point in my code where myArray == [entry1, entry2]. It's not stateless, which from the functional perspective is problematic.

Comment: _"It works fine as in it functions. But it's wrong because it lacks purity and doesn't really fit in with the functional paradigm."_ The working code  is estimated as "wrong" when evaluated from perspective of a matter of "functional paradigm" coding style? Still not gather what the actual requirement is if not using `Object.freeze()`? Are you trying to assign a variable to the awaited value of an asynchronous procedure?

Comment: @guest271314 The problem with using .freeze() here is two things. if I freeze myArray, then I can count on it not mutating and my code will be "right". But myArray will also cease to take entries, and my code will no longer work properly. The other problem is that using .freeze() is the same as admitting defeat for me. The structure of my code is wrong, and I could make it work with .freeze(), but I'd still have coded the structure wrong and I wouldn't be learning anything. Also, ultimately yes, my intention would be to pass the result of my query later on  hence the promises.

Comment: Have you tried using `async/await`? You appear to have several questions relating to different topics.

Comment: `something like` - the problem is, it's not a Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example ... for instance ... what is `resolve` - I'm sure I know, but that's an assumption

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah, I'm already using them in my code. At this point I'm trying to flesh out my knowledge though. I just taught them to myself about an hour ago.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, I took that for granted. I'll adjust my code example.

Comment: async/await is promise "sugar" - it wont help "purifying" the code :p

Comment: @JaromandaX _"async/await is promise "sugar" - it wont help "purifying" the code"_ Your estimation might well be accurate. Perhaps we will be able to help OP achieve requirement and learn the meaning of "immutability" and "purity" as applied to the present Question.

Comment: I already know what OP means by purity

Comment: When speaking of purity, I mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional_programming

Comment: @JaromandaX Well do not, here. "purity" code compared to exactly what "impurity" code? Functional code, and imperative code?

Comment: @JaromandaX How do you suggest converting an event handler function call to a functional programming pattern? Though the code at Question presently does appear to be incomplete.

Comment: I don't suggest it is doable at all, @guest271314

Comment: I've updated the code selection. Pardon any mistakes, I didn't post the full bit before because I'm still getting the hang of Indexeddb and wanted to avoid embarassing myself. Ultimately, I don't know if it is doable. I've very new to indexeddb, ajax, and promises; and I don't know what can or can't be done. I wanted to find out though, and see if anyone might know how to go about it.

Comment: technically, your function `getTable` is pure - changing `myArray` has no effect outside of `getTable` *`A pure function is a function that, given the same input, will always return the same output and does not have any observable side effect.`*

Comment: The function passed to `Promise` constructor needs to be `async` to use `await` within the function body. Is a `SyntaxError` error thrown at code at Question?

Comment: @JaromandaX it's externally pure, but it's not internally pure if that makes sense? myArray itself isn't pure, which bothers me. So I'd still like to learn more. Would you suggest rewording my question?

Comment: What is the expected result? For `getTable()` to return one array or more than one array? How is `getTable()` called?

Comment: No, @Ucenna, I just think as was indirectly pointed out earlier, that it's not possible to avoid mutation given you are working with an event handler

Comment: @Ucenna - I get it now ... it's the handler you see as being impure as it has a side effect outside it's scope .. I doubt that can be avoided

Comment: @guest271314 The expected result is for the code to grab the table and pass it forward. It does that fine. My question isn't about the result itself but rather about the process I took to get to that result.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah. It might be impossible. But I don't want to give up without trying to figure out a way. At the very least, it's a learning opportunity.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/functional-programming-paradigms-in-modern-javascript-pure-functions-797d9abbee1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do several things in the spirit of functional programming, but it is probably not worth it in JavaScript.

For example, to implement immutability arrays, at least in spirit, you simply create and return a new array everytime you want to add an element to an array. I think if I recall my Scheme correctly the function was called `cons`.

```
function push(array, newValue) {
  const copy = copyArray(array);
  copy.push(newValue);
  return copy;
}

function copyArray(array) {
  const copy = [];
  for(const oldValue of array) {
    copy.push(oldValue);
  }
  return copy;
}

// Fancy spread operator syntax implementation if you are so inclined
function copyArray2(inputArray) {
  return [...inputArray];
}
```

Now instead of mutating the input array, you are creating a modified copy of it. Keep in mind this is absolutely horrific performance, and you probably never ever ever want to do this in a real app.

You could take this further probably and use some stack based approach. Again, this is hilariously bad, but it would be something that basically creates a push function that returns a function. The stack increases in size as you append items, and then when you unwind it, it unwinds into an array of values.

My second point is that you can avoid this array building entirely by using newer, less-well-documented features of indexedDB. Specifically, [IDBObjectStore.prototype.getAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/getAll). This function would create the array for you, opaquely, and provided that it is opaque, you will never know about any FP anti-patterns hidden within its abstraction, and therefore are not breaking the rules.

```
function getTable(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    const db = await connect();
    const transaction = await db.transaction(["objectStore"], "readonly");
    const store = await transaction.objectStore("objectStore");
    const request = store.getAll();
    request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
    request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
 }
}
```

My third point is simple, use `db.transaction("objectStore", "readonly");` instead of `db.transaction(["objectStore"], "readonly");`. The array parameter is optional, and it is preferable to keep it simple.

My fourth point is simple, use `db.transaction("objectStore");` instead of `db.transaction(["objectStore"], "readonly");`.  "readonly" is the default mode of a transaction, so there is no need to specify it. The purpose of your code is sufficiently clearly communicated by not specifying the parameter, and omitting the parameter is less verbose.

My fifth point is your use of the `async` specifier(?) in the function definition. You don't need to use it here. You have a synchronous function returning an instance of a `Promise`. If anything, specifying async leads to increased confusion about what your code is doing. Instead, you probably want to be using the async qualifier when *using* the function.

My sixth point is that you are violating some FP principles in your call to `connect()`.  What is `connect` connecting to? Implied global state. This is quite the violation of the spirit of functional programming. Therefore, your connect parameters *must* be parameters to the function itself, so that you do not rely on the implied knowledge of which database is used.

My seventh point is that you are using a database. Functional programmers have so many problems with databases, or any I/O or interaction with the outside world, they seem to like to pretend there is no such thing. Therefore, you probably shouldn't be using a database at all if you want to use functional approach.

My eight point is that connecting within the promise (calling and awaiting `connect`) is definitively an anti-pattern. The goal is to chain promises, so that one starts after the other. Either the caller has to call connect and `then` call `getTable`, or `getTable` has to call `connect` and then do the rest of the promise work.

My ninth point is that I am not even sure how this executes. The executor function that you pass to the `Promise` constructor is not qualified as `async`. So you are using the `await` modifier in a non-qualified function. This should be throwing an error. Technically, a promise swallowed exception, meaning that this promise should always be rejecting.

My tenth point is your use of `async` everywhere. I have no idea what is going on, unless your `connect` function is returning some kind of wrapper library, but calls to `IDBDatabase.prototype.transaction` and `IDBTransaction.prototype.objectStore` are synchronous. It makes no sense why you are awaiting them. They do not return promises.'

My eleventh point is that you are not watching for errors. `request.onsuccess` is not called back when there is an error. This could lead to your promise never settling. You need to also consider the failure case.

My twelfth point is you seem to missing a closing parentheses for your onsuccess handler function. I am not sure how this code ever is interpreted successfully.

Comment: Thank you! That all helps a lot. Answers a lot of questions I didn't even know I had. Do you perchance have any thing you'd suggest to read concerning databases and functional programming. It's something that I've struggled to figure out for a while now. You're right that the functional approach has problems with them. But for code to be useful it usually has to interact with the real world somehow. What is the best way to interact with the real world using functional programming?

Comment: _Functional programmers have so many problems with databases_ Huh? SQL for example is an algebra (relational data sets) and is quite "functional" in itself. FP is not about avoiding state, it is about making state and its handling explicit. Besides, no one would use immutable arrays as in your example. There are various techniques to work with immutable arrays (or lists) and even to eliminate the need of mutable arrays in the first place.